# req.body.[name] is undefined

Tags: node.js, express, undefined, body-parser

I am using:

```
var express    = require("express"),
    app        = express(),
    bodyParser = require("body-parser");
```

with:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

Form:

```
<form action="/[route]" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="[name]">
    <input type="submit" value="Show Results">
</form>
```

Route:

```
app.get("/[route]", function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body.[name]);
});
```

The issue I am having is when I try to access the req.body.[name of input] it is 'undefined'

It's like the body parser is not working and I am not sure why.

Comment: did u try `req.body[name]` ?

Comment: Or just req.body.name and why the hell is there brackets around your name in the post. It would be then req.body["[name]"] have you tried console.log(req.body) to even see what your dealing with.

Comment: @Darkrum, Maybe key - `name` have space(or other character which is not valid for variable name) in it like below
`
var foo = {"a b": 1};
var bar = "a b";
console.log(foo[bar]);
`

Comment: There are a couple mistakes I noticed from code above:
`GET` request does not have a body! It would be better to use `POST` there, and use `req.body[name]` instead of `req.body.[name]`